# Deployed discord bot on heroku, bot won't come online

Tags: java, maven, heroku, bots, discord-jda

I've looked at previous posts, but I don't quite understand them (maybe I'm stupid). One of them advised to a procfile set up as so

`worker: java $JAVA_OPTS -jar <JAR_FILE_PATH>`

but I don't know what that file path would be. I followed the Heroku docs to get this  and am wondering how to get the discord bot online.

Currently, its being deployed with a command prompt line "heroku:deploy-war" as a maven run in intelliJ
[image]

Heres my procfile:`worker: java $JAVA_OPTS -jar target\Disbot-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar`

All in all, this is just a really overcomplicated way to ask "what is the jar file path when doing this thing in heroku?"

If there's a better way to do this or a much more effective way I would be glad to try it out. If additional information is requested, I will provide it if possible.

Comment: Solved the issue - well more found a workaround. Packaged it as a .jar file and realized the Procfile was really just a command prompt thing. Uploaded the jar onto GitHub with the Procfile, that had the text `worker: java -jar Jar.jar`. Even though I didn't get an answer, thanks to anyone who took some time to look at this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Due to Heroku generating the `target` directory in a random `/tmp`, The current answer is not working at the time of this answer (2021-09-18), so I followed these steps from the [Heroku documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/run-non-web-java-processes-on-heroku), using this project structure:

> ```
> .
> ├─ pom.xml
> ├─ Procfile
> └─ src
>    └─ main
>       └─ java
>          └─ com
>             └─ example
>                └─ Main.java
> ```

- Added this build dependency to `pom.xml`:

> ```
> <build>
>     <plugins>
>         <plugin>
>             <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
>             <artifactId>appassembler-maven-plugin</artifactId>
>             <version>1.1.1</enter code hereversion>
>             <configuration>
>                 <assembleDirectory>target</assembleDirectory>
>                 <programs>
>                     <program>
>                         <mainClass>com.example.Main</mainClass>
>                         <name>main</name>
>                     </program>
>             </programs>
>             </configuration>
>             <executions>
>                 <execution>
>                     <phase>package</phase><goals><goal>assemble</goal></goals>
>                 </execution>
>             </executions>
>         </plugin>
>     </plugins>
> </build>
> ```

- Added the `Procfile` with this instruction: `worker: sh target/bin/main`
- Committed the changes and pushed to Heroku's remote.
- Scaled the dyno so it doesn't go to sleep (take into account that you have a maximum amount of hours for your projects): `heroku ps:scale worker=1`

Answer (score 0):

Solved the issue - well more found a workaround. Packaged it as a .jar file and realized the Procfile was really just a command prompt thing. Uploaded the jar onto GitHub with the Procfile, that had the text worker: java -jar Jar.jar. Even though I didn't get an answer, thanks to anyone who took some time to look at this question